# Different number of support vectors & decision values in R (using svm from "e1071") and matlab (fitcsvm) for one class classification

Tags: svm, support-vector-compat

I am trying to run svm both on R and matlab.
Both the codes are giving different results. Even the data used  for both the code is same but they are giving very different results.

Please help me the theory behind both the softwares so that i can get same results when using same data on both the softwares.

Please explain the distance terms for both the software in svm and the theory behind svm for one class classification.

I am expecting same results from both the software. But right now I am not able to understand why the same data is giving different results. Please explain with the help of some example.